# Strange HTTP:Accept-Language behavior instead of Browser Language Detect

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

My *qTranslate-X (v3.4.6.4)* *WordPress (v4.4.2)* plugin can't *"Detect the language of the browser and redirect accordingly."*, so i needed to do a hack by `.htaccess`. Following solution found in Drupal's `.htaccess` (Because none of the stackexchange's answer was working well)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} hu [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hu [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ro [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ro [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Tested under *Window 7* and *Windows 10*, both has the following regional settings:

- Location/Country: *Romania*
- System Language: *English*
- Date and Currency format: *Hungarian*
- Default keyboard language: *hu*

**English** *Google Chrome* with User Agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

redirect to `/hu`

**English** *Internet Explorer* with User Agent:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;
>   MRA 8.2 (build 6901);

redirect to `/hu`

**Any language** *Mozilla Firefox* with User Agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/44.0

redirect to nothing

All cache and History are cleared.

There is any real solution for this!?

Comment: It seems that you're saying that all English browsers except Firefox, in any language, is being redirected to `/hu`, which is what you want, and you're looking for _htaccess_ code that would result in Firefox also being redirected the same way as the other browsers? If so, can you edit the question to clarify that?

Comment: What request headers are being sent by the browsers? Specifically, what is contained in the `Accept-Language` header? (Aside: What is this check for... `%{QUERY_STRING} !(^index.php)`?)